# Running a docker container pulled from Azure Container Registry in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I would like to run a docker container, which i pull from Azure Container Registry. All of this i would like to do in Azure DevOps pipeline.
Firstly i created sample Node.js app and Dockerized it with this tutorial: `https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/`
Then i did my Azure Pipeline which firstly do build&push and then pull and run.
My  pipeline:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Docker pull
      inputs:
        command: pull
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        arguments: container01.azurecr.io/devopsnodejs:latest
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Login to ACR
      inputs:
        command: login
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    - script: |
        docker run -p 49160:8080 -d container01.azurecr.io/devopsnodejs:latest
```

The pipelines runs every step sucessfully, the last script with `docker run` prints this to Azure DevOps console

```
Generating script.
Script contents:
docker run -p 49160:8080 -d ***/devopsnodejs:latest
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/b117892d-e34c-484c-ad8c-f99cd0a97e18.sh
7c6c9d548c4be3e4568e56ffc87cca27e698fc53b5ec15a1595cd45fe72dd143
```

And now the problem is that, I cannot acces the app which should return simply get request saying 'Hello World'
Im trying to go to `localhost:49160`, to `curl -i localhost:49160` but there is only `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 49160 after 2258 ms: Connection refused`

Also, if i do it locally, not in azure pipelines, so I simply run `docker pull container01.azurecr.io/devopsnodejs:latest` and `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d container01.azurecr.io/devopsnodejs:latest` in powershell, the docker ps will show me this container, as well as the `curl -i localhost:49160` will work. Am I able to access this locally, or if i run it in Azure Pipelines it will work only there?

Comment: What do you get if you run the command `docker ps` ?

Comment: @CristianRusanu `docker ps` shows nothing, when im running it locally in powershell, That is what I am asking, it is even possible to run it locally, if I am running this inside azure pipeline?

Comment: @CristianRusanu because if i do it locally, not in azure pipelines, so I simply run `docker pull container01.azurecr.io/devopsnodejs:latest` and `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d container01.azurecr.io/devopsnodejs:latest` in powershell, the `docker ps` will show me this container, as well as the `curl -i localhost:49160` will work.

Comment: The way I do it is to use a `bash@3` task and use a script that runs ssh. I'll try to summarize in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this question already, which is I think your scenario?

[Cannot conect to Docker container running in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166372/cannot-conect-to-docker-container-running-in-vsts)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bash script with ssh to logon to the target machine and perform docker commands on the machine. The following is just an example. I have something like this in one of my pipelines.

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: "Deploy image $(imageName)"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    failOnStderr: false
    script: |
        sshpass -p '$(localroot-userpassword)' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $(localroot-username)@$(remoteHost) "{ sudo docker stop $(imageName) ; sudo docker rm $(imageName) ; sudo docker pull $(imageName) ; sudo docker run ...#add other commands separated by semicolon}"
```